# How to programmatically send break signal (Magic SysRq) through serial terminal

Tags: shell-script, signals, serial-port, terminal-emulator, serial-console

I have 2 computers connected by serial connection (null modem) emulating vt220. I'd like to send a break signal (Magic SysRq) from a shell script. How can I do that without writing a custom program?

Comment: Try `python -c 'import termios; termios.tcsendbreak(2,0)' 2>/dev/yourdevicename`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Please post it as an answer so I may accept it (I used handle instead of 2 but that's minor detail).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is typically done using the [tcsendbreak](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tcsendbreak.html) C library routine. You can get to this from the shell by using a Python or Perl one-liner:

```
python -c 'import termios; termios.tcsendbreak(3, 0)' 3>/dev/yourdevicename

perl -e 'use POSIX; tcsendbreak(3, 0)' 3>/dev/yourdevicename
```